# Mousepad edge scrolling disabled in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, scrolling

As you can see there is no option for enabling `edge scrolling` in Ubuntu 18.04. Now I can only scroll with two fingers, which it sucks.

How can I enable edge scrolling in Ubuntu 18.04?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems you didn't install whole packages, or packages are not up-to-date

install the following package:

```
apt update
apt install xserver-xorg-input-libinput
```

Or install and upgrade whole ubuntu packages this way

open a terminal and type

```
apt update
apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

if nothing happened generate new /etc/apt/sources.list from [this link](https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) and **repeat** steps above

If still you have the problem mayble you need a **full upgrade**:

```
apt update
apt full-upgrade
```

---

after package steps you can enable it, this way:

Settings > Mouse & Touchpad > "Uncheck" Two finger scroll

Settings screenshot:

[image: Edge Scrolling setting]

OR:

Settings > Devices > Mouse & Touchpad > Edge Scrolling

[image: Enabled Edge Scrolling setting]

This is also accessible via [DConf Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yjp2f.png) as well. Go to org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad and set:

```
 scroll-method: edge-scrolling
```

[image: edge-scrolling]

Comment: It's possible OP question is about Ubuntu Unity and your answer is about Ubuntu Gnome?

Comment: 18.04 upgraded from 16.04 provides both `Unity` and `GDM`. The OP's screen shot looks like Unity to me.

Comment: I changed it a little bit, and add both Mouse & Keyboard Settings

Answer (score 1):

If using a unity session then you need to install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
package, ie. 
`sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`

Answer (score 0):

I have Dell Vostro 3400. In Ubuntu 20.04, I had same problem. It seems that the problem caused by the inappropriate driver.

By `xinput` I found out that my touchpad driver should be **synaptics**. So remove all **libinput** packages by running `sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput*` and installing **synaptics** by `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`. Note that don't install other xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-* packages.

After restart, It works.